# Why running seeder with uuid field under Postgres invalid input syntax for type uuid error is raised?

Tags: laravel, postgresql

I try to move laravel 9 from mysql into Postgres  12.11
and got error during initial seeding :

```
          SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type uuid: 
"26519615-106e-4a8a-biyf-2693e370531e" (SQL: insert into "media" ("collection_name", "conversions_disk", "custom_properties", "disk", "file_name", "generated_conversions", "id", "manipulations", "mime_type", "model_id", "model_type", "name", "order_column", "responsive_images", "size", "uuid") 
    values (currency_app, public, [], public, john_doe.jpg, [], 12, [], image/jpg, 3, App\Models\User, b22de6732bca17190523c285e1c4a9b5, 
12, [], 25670, 26519615-106e-4a8a-biyf-2693e370531e))
```

Which is raised by line :

```
\DB::table('media')->insert(array(   // that is table of spatie/laravel-medialibrary 10
    array(
        'id'                    => 12,
        'model_type'            => 'App\\Models\\User',
        'model_id'              => 3,
        'uuid'                  => '26519615-106e-4a8a-biyf-2693e370531e',
        'collection_name'       => 'currency_app',
        'name'                  => 'b22de6732bca17190523c285e1c4a9b5',
        'file_name'             => 'john_doe.jpg',
        'mime_type'             => 'image/jpg',
        'disk'                  => 'public',
        'conversions_disk'      => 'public',
        'size'                  => 25670,
        'manipulations'         => '[]',
        'custom_properties'     => '[]',
        'generated_conversions' => '[]',
        'responsive_images'     => '[]',
        'order_column'          => 12,
    ),
));
```

In migration file field is defined as :

```
$table->uuid('uuid')->nullable()->unique();
```

under phppgadmin I see that field “uuid” has uuid type with UNIQUE restriction.

In composer.json :

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.0.2",
        "bensampo/laravel-enum": "^5.3",
        "cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable": "^9.0",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^3.3",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0.5",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "inertiajs/inertia-laravel": "^0.5.2",
        "intervention/image": "^2.7",
        "laravel/framework": "^v9.6.0",
        "laravel/horizon": "^5.9",
        "laravel/jetstream": "^2.6",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.14",
        "laravel/telescope": "^4.7",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.7",
        "orangehill/iseed": "^3.0",
        "predis/predis": "^1.1",
        "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^7.0",
        "spatie/laravel-medialibrary": "^10.0.0",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^5.5",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "*",
        "tightenco/ziggy": "^1.4.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nascent-africa/jetstrap": "^2.5",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "app/Library/helper.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
                "laravel/telescope"
            ]
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

How this error can be fixed ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So where does the invalid UUID `26519615-106e-4a8a-biyf-2693e370531e` come from?

Comment: to declare an uuid key, you can use this in your migration file  : **$table->uuid('id')->primary();**

Comment: Do you mean that value "26519615-106e-4a8a-biyf-2693e370531e" is invalid ? it has length in 36 chars. It was written in seeder file manually and worked ok on mysql

Comment: In migration file this field as described as $table->uuid('uuid')->nullable()->unique();

Comment: A uuid is composed of hex characters, 0-9 and a-f (either case). `y` is not a valid hex digit so the entire uuid is invalid.